# PHPmailer works on localhost but not work on heroku

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

PHPMailer works at localhost phpmyadmin, but not work after I deployed on heroku, It seems that PHPMailer has authenticate problem on heroku. Anyone knows the reason?

```
$to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Aliens Abducted Me - Abduction Report';
$msg = "$name was abducted $when_it_happened and was gone for $how_long.\n" .
"Number of aliens: $how_many\n" .
"Alien description: $alien_description\n" .
"What they did: $what_they_did\n" .
"Fang spotted: $fang_spotted\n" .
"Other comments: $other";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->  SMTPDebug=2;
$mail ->  isSMTP();
$mail ->  Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail ->  SMTPAuth =true;
$mail ->  Username='xxx@gmail.com';
$mail ->  Password= 'correct password';
$mail ->  SMTPSecure ='tls';
$mail ->  Port =587;

$mail ->  setFrom($to);
$mail ->  addAddress($to);

$mail ->  addReplyTo($to);
$mail ->  Subject=$subject;
$mail ->  Body=$msg;
$mail ->  send();
```

And this is the error I got

```
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP                      y29sm10762113qtk.47 - gsmtp
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO immense-bayou-46149.herokuapp.com
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.158.107.41]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO immense-bayou-46149.herokuapp.com
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [54.158.107.41]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbty534-5.7.14 OxYqa_vgUvCRSPkrtCYvPqBkjM-c0OPhKwgtdEA-4Du9zmkqJK4-wc6EnlEwORPnhd5VeD534-5.7.14 nGYK31F2CT1owGvIlWvSuyfXZ7YYqHnRK7y8HCRQR3OmDf9VC1YbXjy2lfanNuSZq1NLMB534-5.7.14 X1F27an8Z_tB7u9-an0ree4tmC6TUr6TuUnmxaybqouLZDiTGy1coPfbeD4JLr0CL59SSY534-5.7.14 U-Qigx5DTQIaZ8H0onzz3s9E-sLpg> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y29sm10762113qtk.47 - gsmtp
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbty534-5.7.14 OxYqa_vgUvCRSPkrtCYvPqBkjM-c0OPhKwgtdEA-4Du9zmkqJK4-wc6EnlEwORPnhd5VeD534-5.7.14 nGYK31F2CT1owGvIlWvSuyfXZ7YYqHnRK7y8HCRQR3OmDf9VC1YbXjy2lfanNuSZq1NLMB534-5.7.14 X1F27an8Z_tB7u9-an0ree4tmC6TUr6TuUnmxaybqouLZDiTGy1coPfbeD4JLr0CL59SSY534-5.7.14 U-Qigx5DTQIaZ8H0onzz3s9E-sLpg> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y29sm10762113qtk.47 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2018-01-29 23:50:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-01-29 23:50:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection y29sm10762113qtk.47 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: You need to put in a little more effort. The phrase "Please log in via your web browser and then try again" in the error message gives you a huge hint. This is also covered in the troubleshooting guide linked from the error message. It's not exactly hard to find.

Comment: check your credentials

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Gmail isn't working, but I strongly urge you to use a more appropriate service.

Heroku has good [support for sending mail](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp)  using a [variety of production-grade email services](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/email-sms). I've personally used [SendGrid](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid) and been quite happy with it.

You can use [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to configure your mailing settings, e.g. to point your development machine at a tool like [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) and point your production Heroku machine to SendGrid.